# Finding the largest three-digits number "within" a number

Tags: c++, algorithm, search

For this question, I need to find the largest three-digit number within a larger number.

> Sample Test Case 1:
>  534535 
>  Output: 
>  535
>
> ---
>
> Sample Test Case 2 : 
>  23457888976 
>  Output : 
>  976

---

I've tried the following code:

```cpp
        #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;
        int main() {
        int num;
        cin>>num;
        int len= to_string(num).length();
        int arr[10],lnum=0,max=0;
        for (int i =len-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
        arr[i] = num%10;
        num =num/10;    //to convert int into array
        }
        for (int i=0;i<len-2;i++)
        {
        if (arr[i] >arr[i+1])
            lnum = arr[i]*100+arr[i+1]*10+arr[i];
        if (lnum>max)
            max= lnum;  
        }
        cout<<max;
        return 0;
    }
```

---

Although this code seems to work for Test Case 1, it doesn't work for most of the inputs.

---

(Please do help with this too. ) 
1. This is for numbers with 10-digits only (that too, most of it have wrong output). What to do in case of bigger numbers? 
2. Is there any better way to convert the integer into an array? Or will a string array work in similar way? 
3. It's really slow, can anyone help me figure out how to speed this up?

---

Thanks for any help !!

Comment: Analyze them as strings rather than numbers. It's far more straightforward and less likely to produce an error

Comment: use sliding window algorithm

Comment: Hint: `n % 1000` extracts the rightmost three digits of `n`. `n /= 10` removes the final digit from `n`. Don't forget to consider the case of negative `n`. Your test cases are evil - both largest numbers are at the end. Do test with some more. Another note: using a string method may not be such a bad idea given you are loading from standard input anyway.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes thnx, can you help me with the code?

Comment: Sure, where did you get stuck? ;)

Comment: @neilharia7, if we use sliding algo, it'll still not work cause it's the position of the digits, not the sum of the digits that matter. Although, it'll make the process a bit easier. For ex, 287782 might not produce the required output. I'll need another condition to check it once more. But still, thanks

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes, I'm still working on that. But still, could this way work out somehow?

Comment: Are you asking to debug this code? `arr[i]*100+arr[i+1]*10+arr[i]` is definitely not alright

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes yes please, any debugs for this code?

Comment: `arr[i]*100+arr[i+1]*10+arr[i+2]`?

Comment: The key to a simple solution here is to recognize that this question is about **text**, not about numeric values as such. Don't read into an `int`; read into `std::string`. Search for the highest digit in the string; if there's only one of that digit, you're done. If there's more than one, look at the next digit.

Comment: @PeteBecker, thanks I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i, n;
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    n = (int)s.size();
    if(n<3){
        /* there are less than 3 digits in the input number
        Here, you can print the number itself as it will be largest number or
        print -1 which can state that no 3 digit number exists.
        */
        cout<<-1;
        return 0;
    }
    int maxans = (s[0]-'0')*100 + (s[1]-'0')*10 + (s[2]-'0');
    // storing the first 3 digits as the maximum answer till now.
    int prev = maxans;
    for(i = 3;i<n;i++){
        int cur = (prev%100)*10 + (s[i]-'0'); // using %100 to extract the last two digits and then multiplying by 10 and adding the ith digit to make the next 3 digit number.
        maxans = max(maxans, cur);
        prev = cur;
    }
    cout<<maxans;
    return 0;
}
```

This code is of time complexity O(n) where n is the length of input string and space complexity O(1)

Answer (score 1):

This approach will work with any big number you can store in variable. The approach is as follows,

First convert number into string and then create an array of all possible numbers of 3 digits as showed below,

Number = `534535`
All possible 3 digits number array = `["534", "345", "453", "535"]`

Then sort this array, after sorting last element will be max number of three digit, as highlighted below,
Sorted array = ["345", "453", "534", `"535"`]

Another example,
Number = `23457888976`
All possible  3 digits number array = `["234", "345", "457", "578", "788", "888", "889", "897", "976"]`
After sorting, last element is max number as highlighted below
Sorted array = ["234", "345", "457", "578", "788", "888", "889", "897", `"976"`]

**Note**: `Radix sort` will perform better then `std::sort()`, `std::sort()` offers `Quick sort`. Radix sort is ideal for string sorting and specially in this case because max bucket size is only 10 (possible range 0-9), but you have to implement `radix sort` your self.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;

std::vector<std::string> allThreeDigitNumbers(const std::string& numStr){

    std::vector<std::string> allNumStr(numStr.size() - 2, std::string("000"));
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator aIt = allNumStr.begin();

    for(std::string::const_iterator it = numStr.cbegin(), lastIt = it + (numStr.size() - 2); lastIt != it; ++it, ++aIt){

        std::copy(it, it + 3, aIt->begin());
    }

    return allNumStr;
}

unsigned maxThreeDigitNumberInNumber(unsigned long long num){

    std::string numStr = std::to_string(num);

    if(numStr.size() < 3){

        return 0;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> allNumStr = allThreeDigitNumbers(numStr);

    std::sort(allNumStr.begin(), allNumStr.end());

    return std::stoul(allNumStr.back());
}

int main(){
    cout<< "Max 3 digits number of 534535 => "<< maxThreeDigitNumberInNumber(534535)<< '\n';
    cout<< "max 3 digits number of 23457888976 => "<< maxThreeDigitNumberInNumber(23457888976)<< '\n';
}
```

Output

```
Max 3 digits number of 534535 => 535
max 3 digits number of 23457888976 => 976
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments to understand the code below:

```cpp
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/hana/functional/partial.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <range/v3/to_container.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/all.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/drop.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/subrange.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/take.hpp>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/all_of.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::hana;
using namespace ranges;
using namespace ranges::views;

auto constexpr is9 = partial(std::equal_to<>{}, 9);

template<typename Range>
Range fun(Range const& r) {
    if (r.size() == 3) {                   // 3 digits only?
        return r;                              // this is the result
    } else if (all_of(r | take(3), is9)) { // 999?
        return r | take(3);                    // nothing better than this!
    } else {                               // otherwise?
        auto tail = r | drop(1);               // drop the first to get the tail
        if (r.front() < tail.front()) {        // if the first is less the the tip of the tail
            return fun(tail);                      // then let the first go and recurse on the tail
        } else {                               // otherwise
            auto result = std::max(                // get the maximum between
                    r | take(3) | to<std::string>, // the current first three
                    fun(tail)   | to<std::string>  // and the result of recursing on the tail
                    );
            return result;                         // and that's the result
        }
    }
    return r;
}

int main() {
    std::string s1 = "534535";
    std::string s2 = "23457888976";
    assert((fun(subrange(s1)) | to<std::string>) == std::string{"535"});
    assert((fun(subrange(s2)) | to<std::string>) == std::string{"976"});
}
```

The number is treated as a string, and since we need to compare (sub-)strings of length 3, the lexicographic `operator<` for `std::string`s gives us the same result as the arithmetic `operator<` would give for the two corresponding numbers.

The logic is:

- we start from left and recurse to the right if needed
- in the case of only 3 digits left, `r.size() == 3`, we return all of them, `return r;`
- in the case of three leading nines, `all_of(r | take(3), is9)`, we trivially return those three, `return r | take(3);`;
- otherwise, we take the `std::max` between the leading 3-digit string, `r | take(3) | to<std::string>`, and the `std::string` we obtain by recursing on the rest of the sequence without the first digit, `fun(tail) | to<std::string>`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in Python3**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

num = input("Enter the number : ")

if len(num) == 3:
    print(f"Largest digit is : {num}")
    exit(0)
elif len(num) < 3:
    print(-1)
    exit(0)

maxans = int((num[0].replace("0", "")))*100 + int((num[1].replace("0", "")))*10 + int((num[2].replace("0", "")))
prev = maxans

for i in range(3, 6):
    cur = (prev%100)*10 + int((num[i].replace("0", "")))
    maxans = max(maxans, cur)
    prev = cur

print(f"The Largest num = : {maxans}")
```